# Android layout as button with selectable functionality

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I'm trying to create a button-like component, with a left-aligned ImageView and then 2 TextViews to the right of the ImageView, stacked one above the other and formatted differently, like the following example:.

```
 __________________________
|                          |
| |-----|  Bold Main Text  | 
| |Image|                  |
| |-----|  Small Sub Text  |
|__________________________|
```

I also want the ImageView to change depending on the click state of the outer container, much like a standard button would do with a selectable resource associated with it.   So that when I click anywhere in the outer box the image selectable state is changed.

I know I can use a Button, setting the 'drawableLeft' property to create a single line of text associated with an Image as a button, but it seems I can only have a single item of text using this strategy.

Has anyone implemented any UI components like this in the past?

Thanks!

Comment: Well you can use your own layout, and add an OnClickListener to it, so it will begave like a button. For the image change on click state, that would probably require more complex logic in the listener, and maybe the use of an onTouchListener instead

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to the `ImageView` widget. Also you need to make the `ImageView`'s parent clickable and focusable.

The `RelativeLayout` in the following code will act as a `Button`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout:height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:duplicateParentState="true" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:duplicateParentState="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Awesome solution! Been trying to do this for hours now. This made my day. Thanks!

Comment: People like you make SO great!