# How do I add a text background to a button in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-activity

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTalG.jpg]

I've designed buttons as shown in the image above. But I'm unable to add the text background (which is circled) to the button.
How to achieve that?

Here is what I have achieved so far:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/centerVertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/centerHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/today_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/centerVertical"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerHorizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:background="@drawable/button1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Today"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextweek_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/centerVertical"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/centerHorizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
    android:layout_marginRight="20px"
    android:background="#EF5350"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Next Week"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/later_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/centerVertical"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerHorizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:background="#66BB6A"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Later"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/range_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/centerVertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/centerHorizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
    android:layout_marginRight="20px"
    android:background="#5C6BC0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Range"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
</Button>
```

[XML Layout](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_acM7_FSVJycEFxZF8wLXhCTjA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Show your layout file

Comment: What you want background to text only? Let say background to LeaderBoard text?

Comment: show the XML and mention what you wanna do here, your question is a little bit confusing

Comment: @Abhishek Yes.It will be like this.
Button having a background as image. On which at the bottom of the image, there will be a text.
From the above image, There is a button called as Leader board right. In which at the bottom, there is a text and it also has a different background color.
How to achieve this?

Comment: You will use custom layout for this task

Comment: @JEGADEESANS How to do that?
Any tuts or source available?

Comment: Button has some restriction for customization. For example you put play image in your button. If you want to create more customized button then use custom layout. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821954/android-layout-as-button-with-selectable-functionality

Comment: I think you XML layout is different.

Comment: Layout can act like button in more customized way.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/centerVertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
    android:layout_marginRight="20px"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/centerHorizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/range_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#5C6BC0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Range"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#061FAF"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/mail_icon"
        android:text="range text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've done this for one button..  If it helps you can do changes accordingly to other buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with adding RelativeLayout instead of Button.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" 
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Just set text to `TextView` and add source to `Button`.

Comment: @ImAtWar But that will not satisfy for all the buttons.
Say if I have 4 in the activity.

Comment: @Abhishek could you explain your question? What do you mean?

Comment: I want to achieve 2x2 buttons in a grid type.
Exactly as shown in the image in the description.
How can I do that?

Comment: Just think your RelativeLayout is button, give onClick to RelativeLayouts instead of buttons.

Comment: But How do I get the text and a different background for the text as circled in the image?

Comment: add this line 'android:textColor="#000000" '  to each TextView and give color which you want.

Comment: That will give a color to the text. 
But I want the text background!

Comment: Then add 'android:background="@color/colorAccent" to RelativeLayout. If you mean this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:oreantation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8823469/5898862

This is best solution for creating customized button using layout. You can easily set background color using `android:background` property

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, what you want is - You need a button background color which is similar/near to image on it.?

In Android Version 5.0, a class is added which help you to extract color from bitmap. [Palette](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html)

Below is the sample code which you will get the respective background from  the image and later you can set it to the button.

```
Palette.generateAsync(bitmap, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
    public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
        // You will get color here
    }
});
```

Possible combination of colors are:

1. Vibrant
2. Vibrant Dark
3. Vibrant Light
4. Muted
5. Muted Dark
6. Muted Light

To use above class add the following dependencies in your project:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

======================or=========================

Another way is you can get respective color by image bitmap:

```
public static int getRespectiveColor(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 1, 1, true);
    final int color = newBitmap.getPixel(0, 0);
    newBitmap.recycle();
    return color;
}
```

Hope above both will solve your problem. :) cheers!!!